# Is there a way to deploy DropWizard in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, dropwizard

Is there a way to deploy DropWizard in JBoss? We are required to use JBoss anyway but don't want to miss out trying DropWizard. Came to know about wiztowar but current DropWizard version 0.7.1 (which is tailored to support JDK 7+ and likely to be supported in future) does not seem to have equivalent in wiztowar, whose last version is suited only for DropWizard 0.6.2? Is there a way out?

Thanks,
Padmanabhan

Comment: JBoss and DW are two totally different concepts. I do not know wiztowar, but I doubt that mixing those concepts will get you anywhere, even if the tool works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/rvs-fluid-it/dw-jar-to-war. The project is in its early stages. But it is already working on Tomcat 7 and Weblogic 12c. The DropWizard version is 0.8. Feel free to test it on JBoss. I welcome feedback.